# Convert DateTimeOffset - UTC to LocalTime (CurrentCulture)

Tags: c#

I have a NET Core 5 API (with localization) and i need to convert DateTimeOffset values (like as 2021-07-03 15:55:07.0000000 +00:00) to localtime/zonetime using 'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture". It is possible? Thx

```
if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
{
    if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(propertyValue.ToString(), out var dateTimeOffset))
    {
        propertyValue = ¿¿??;
    }
}
```

Comment: `dateTimeOffset.ToLocalTime()` maybe

Comment: `CurrentCulture` doesn't uniquely determine time zone. So it's not clear what you are asking. The [`ToLocalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tolocaltime) method will return a `DateTimeOffset` value converted to the system's currently configured local time. Why doesn't that work for you? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68249548/edit) to make it more clear.

Comment: Please note: your question does not appear to be _about_ ASP.NET, so the use of that tag is inappropriate. I've removed it for you.

Comment: The basic .NET time and date handling often leaves you wanting more. Take a look at Noda time https://nodatime.org/

Comment: Check out `TimeZoneInfo`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=net-5.0. It should have what you need. You will need a way to configure or let the user specify a time zone if you don't want to rely on local server time (which often is NOT what people care about).

Comment: @Charlieface Hi, that doesn't work for me, "ToLocalTime ()" apparently uses the Culture of the computer it is running on and not the culture I use in the "Accept-Language" header. For example if i use "es-ES" the date format changes (that is correct), but the "zonetime" is always "-03: 00" (im in argentina) and Spain have "+02:00"

Comment: Remember language does not equal time zone. The continental USA has 4 time zones.  Australia has like 5 or 6. So if you want to truly support international users you need to make your application and/or APIs time zone configurable whenever it matters.

Comment: What about `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` obviously you need to know the *exact* time zone, not just the culture or language

Comment: @Peter and Russia has 11, ranging from UTC+2 to UTC+12, despite all being covered by ru-RU.

Comment: OP: another point on trying to base time on the Accept-Language header: I'm British but I live in Japan. My browser is configured for English (UK) as my default choice, followed by English, finally followed by Japanese. It is presently almost 10am in Japan and 2am in the UK. If you served me a page based on my language header, the times would be 8 hours out, and then 9 hours out when the clocks go back in the UK later this year (Japan doesn't do daylight savings, the UK does).